# studying for prolog/haskell programming exam

Tags: syntax, prolog

I starting to study for my upcoming exam and I'm stuck on a trivial prolog practice question which is not a good sign lol.

It should be really easy, but for some reason I cant figure it out right now.

The task is to simply count the number of odd numbers in a list of Int in prolog. 
I did it easily in haskell, but my prolog is terrible. Could someone show me an easy way to do this, and briefly explain what you did?

So far I have:

```
odd(X):- 1 is X mod 2.

countOdds([],0).
countOdds(X|Xs],Y):-
?????
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Prolog you use recursion to inspect elements of recursive data structs, as lists are.
Pattern matching allows selecting the right rule to apply.
The trivial way to do your task:

You have a list = [X|Xs], for each each element X, if is odd(X) return countOdds(Xs)+1 else return countOdds(Xs).

```
countOdds([], 0).
countOdds([X|Xs], C) :-
  odd(X),
  !, % this cut is required, as rightly evidenced by Alexander Serebrenik
  countOdds(Xs, Cs),
  C is Cs + 1.
countOdds([_|Xs], Cs) :-
  countOdds(Xs, Cs).
```

Note the `if`, is handled with a different rule with `same` pattern: when Prolog find a non odd element, it backtracks to the last rule.

ISO Prolog has syntax sugar for `If Then Else`, with that you can write

```
countOdds([], 0).
countOdds([X|Xs], C) :-
  countOdds(Xs, Cs),
  (  odd(X)
  -> C is Cs + 1
  ;  C is Cs
  ).
```

In the first version, the recursive call follows the test `odd(X)`, to avoid an useless visit of list'tail that should be repeated on backtracking.

**edit** Without the cut, we get multiple execution path, and so possibly incorrect results under 'all solution' predicates (findall, setof, etc...)

This last version put in evidence that the procedure isn't `tail recursive`. To get a tail recursive procedure add an `accumulator`:

```
countOdds(L, C) :- countOdds(L, 0, C).

countOdds([], A, A).
countOdds([X|Xs], A, Cs) :-
  (  odd(X)
  -> A1 is A + 1
  ;  A1 is A
  ),
  countOdds(Xs, A1, Cs).
```

Comment: thanks alot, really helped me out on this question plus other problems I had :)

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of odd/1 is fine.

The fact for the empty list is also fine.

IN the recursive clause you need to distinguish between odd numbers and even numbers. If the number is odd, the counter should be increased:

```
countOdds([X|Xs],Y1) :- odd(X), countOdds(Xs,Y), Y1 is Y+1.
```

If the number is not odd (=even) the counter should not be increased.

```
countOdds([X|Xs],Y) :- \+ odd(X), countOdds(Xs,Y).
```

where `\+` denotes negation as failure.

Alternatively, you can use ! in the first recursive clause and drop the condition in the second one:

```
countOdds([X|Xs],Y1) :- odd(X), !, countOdds(Xs,Y), Y1 is Y+1.

countOdds([X|Xs],Y) :- countOdds(Xs,Y).
```